# Post request with bearer token and get access token in response with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-post, bearer-token, net-http

I have access to API with bearer token and I'm getting the response in INSOMNIA / Postman tool with below values:

```
{
    "access_token": "ki1AH9hiF8_OTGr70VnOnb-I7ZRWVI3u6pXxWHW6hStckd3WC3NLviN0Z036dvBVfEQFWO691t-9roX-p1w6gou1TlWAqEwX3mmLwcZ4VcwrS5YWY8GLSxjBCSMdcn5RLBPfh5jubNX8_vrrX3D3bTbsGnxE1jeWf_T-lnUGEkWz876o3kbonIFWwJMO8-athkcfb3kPoqOrD1w2CRyeDADFvYuPiTpbiG75a9s1V-qdgTGdYaP8-FRnm0G0zhKt8lQo2W8pBBa4dMv-5jQSEA",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 14399
}
```

But when I'm trying to get the same thing from the ruby script I'm only getting response code as 200OK as below:

```
[1] pry(main)> response = http.request(request)
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

I have written the below rake task to get access token in the response to post request:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

desc "post request and get response"
task :post_request_and_get_response => :environment do
  uri = URI.parse("my_url")

  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request["Authorization"] = 'Bearer token'
  request["Content-Type"] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  request.set_form_data({"grant_type" => "password", "username" => "user", "password" => "my_password"})
  p response = http.request(request)
end
```

Please help me to get access_token in response to the post request that I can see in the Postman or Insomnia tools.

As through rake tasks, I'm only getting the 200OK status code.

In `response.body` I'm only getting the below values instead of access_token

```
[12] pry(main)> response.body
=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV=\"CONTENT-TYPE\" CONTENT=\"TEXT/HTML; CHARSET=utf-8\"/><title>Error</title></head><body><H2>Error</H2><table summary=\"Error\" border=\"0\" bgcolor=\"#FEEE7A\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"400\"><tr><td><table summary=\"Error\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"1\"><tr valign=\"top\" bgcolor=\"#FBFFDF\" align=\"left\"><td><STRONG>Error</STRONG></td></tr><tr valign=\"top\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><td>This page can't be displayed. Contact support for additional information.<br/>The incident ID is: N/A.</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why I'm getting the response values in Insomnia/postman tool and not getting through my rake tasks. Do I need to change anything? Please help me.

Comment: This question is not duplicate as you marked it. My situation is different @Зелёный

Answer (score 2):

You can get response body and parse it as JSON code:

```
require 'JSON'

body = response.body
data = JSON.parse body
puts data['access_token']
```

Hope it helps.
[image]

Comment: that is not working.

Comment: In response I'm only getting this value => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true> nothing else.

Comment: `response` is a object, you can see my simple example in image.

Comment: Problem here is your JSON syntax is wrong, It must be: ```{
   "access_token" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}```

Comment: @hoangdd please check the updated question. Exact response I'm getting on Insomnia / postman tool.

Comment: Why I'm getting the response values in Insomnia/postman tool and not getting through my rake tasks. Do I need to change anything? Please help me.

Comment: The thing is I'm not getting response body what I want in fact through rake task.

Comment: Can you post parameters and headers when you make request on postman?